# Does Android's DataBinding work with the Transitions/Scenes framework?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-transitions, android-databinding

Does Android's [DataBinding](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) library work with the [Transitions framework](http://developer.android.com/training/transitions/overview.html)?

```
        Scene scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(this, R.layout.creditcardentryview_scene2_expanded, this.getContext());
        TransitionManager.go(scene);
        scene2Binding = CreditcardentryviewScene2ExpandedBinding.bind(this);
```

Attempting the code above throws this error: `view tag isn't correct on view:null`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should bind the layout prior to creating the Scene:

```
CreditcardentryviewScene2ExpandedBinding binding = CreditcardentryviewScene2ExpandedBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), this, false);
Scene scene = new Scene(this, binding.getRoot());
TransitionManager.go(scene);
```

The `bind(this)` is failing because `this` isn't a bound view. `this` is the scene root! So you can also do this:

```
Scene scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(this, R.layout.creditcardentryview_scene2_expanded, this.getContext());
TransitionManager.go(scene);
scene2Binding = CreditcardentryviewScene2ExpandedBinding.bind(this.getChildAt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You must inflate the view yourself with `DataBindingUtil.inflate()`

and construct the scene with the inflated view.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Scene.html#Scene(android.view.ViewGroup, android.view.ViewGroup)

`.bind(this)` still fails though, so you have to manually managed the generated binding.